# Open installed software with terminal

Tags: terminal, skype

I have installed `skype` from the terminal on my Ubuntu with `sudo apt install skype`.

Now, how can I open `skype` from the terminal?

Comment: `dpkg -l skype` should show the list of files installed.

Comment: how do i open/Launch it ?

Comment: Depending on which version you have installed, you type skype or skypeforlinux. You have not provided the version of your ubuntu. There is a good chance you installed Skype 4.x which is no longer supported. See https://wiki.debian.org/skype for more information. Goto https://go.skype.com/linux.deb to get the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the way to run a command is by typing the name of the command and hitting enter. So, almost certainly, all you need to do is open a terminal, type `skype` (or `skypeforlinux` if you installed the new native version) and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If you don't know the name of the command you just installed, you can use `dpkg-query -L packageName` to list the contents of the just installed package, and search for things placed in a directory called `bin` (most, although not all, executables are placed in various `bin` directories).

For skype, specifically, things are slightly more complex because it is in two packages, not one: `skype` and `skype-bin`. So you would need to run:

```
$ dpkg-query -L skype-bin skype | grep '/bin'
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/skype
```

That shows you that there is a file called `skype` in `/usr/bin`, so as I said in the beginning, all you need to do to run it is to type`skype` in your terminal and hit  <kbd>Enter</kbd>.